# C++, how do I printf a substr?

Tags: c++

I'm just trying to print out a substring via printf, but keep getting an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string argv1 = argv[1];

  if (argc == 2 && argv1.length() > 3) {
    printf("%s\n", argv1.substr(0, 2));
  }
}
```

The error is showing:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2
> has type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string*’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: Your issue is that `std::string::substr` returns a `std::string` type.  You'll need to convert the return value to a `char *`, a.k.a. `c_str()`.

Comment: you print a substring like you print a string. dont you get the same warning for `printf("%s\n", argv1);` ?

Comment: You have marked this post as C++ ... glad to see string, but to learn C++'isms, you should use cout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` with `%s` expects a `char *`, but `string::substr` returns another `std::string`.  You can get the underlying `char*` from the string via the `c_str()` method.

```
 printf("%s\n", argv1.substr(0, 2).c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` specifier of `printf()` expects a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated string, not a `std::string` object. That is what the warning is complaining about.

You need to use the `std::string::c_str()` method when passing a `std::string` to `%s`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string argv1 = argv[1];

  if (argc == 2 && argv1.length() > 3) {
    std::printf("%s\n", argv1.substr(0, 2).c_str());
  }
}
```

But, that being said, you really should not be using `printf()` in C++ to begin with, use `std::cout` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string argv1 = argv[1];

  if (argc == 2 && argv1.length() > 3) {
    std::cout << argv1.substr(0, 2) << "\n";
  }
}
```